# Download mysql gzipped backup with phpseclib to local system

Tags: php, gzip, mysql, phpseclib

i am using phpseclib on my local pc to download mysqldummp from a remote server this is my code:

```
set_include_path( './phpseclib');
require_once 'NET/SSH2.php';
require_once 'NET/SFTP.php';
require_once 'Crypt/RSA.php';
require_once 'Math/BigInteger.php';

$privatekey = file_get_contents('/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPassword('');

if ($rsa->loadKey($privatekey, CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1 ) === false) {
exit ("private key loading failed!");

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('example.com');
if (!$ssh->login('root', $rsa)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); // tried removing this line too

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=sql.tar.gz");
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
header("Content-Encoding: application/x-gzip");
echo $ssh->exec('mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbname tablename | gzip -9');
```

when i open this page in my browser on my localhost it is prompting to download file sql.tar.gz , but file is not extracting it seems it is corrupt.
can you guys plz tell me if i am doing anything wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you might have better luck with `header('Content-Encoding: gzip');` then with the Content-Encoding you are using.
2. When I tried to do `mysqldump -uuser -ppass dbname tablename | gzip -9` I got the following:

   ```
   gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
   For help, type: gzip -h
   mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
   ```

   If you remove all the headers and do an strlen() on `$ssh->exec()`'s output, what do you get? I'm wondering if what you're getting back is even being compressed at all. If not then maybe try the `-f` option that the command I ran suggested.
3. Your code can be cleaned up a lot.

   ```
   set_include_path( './phpseclib');
   require_once 'NET/SSH2.php';
   require_once 'NET/SFTP.php';
   require_once 'Crypt/RSA.php';
   require_once 'Math/BigInteger.php';

   $privatekey = file_get_contents('/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa');

   $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
   $rsa->setPassword('');

   if ($rsa->loadKey($privatekey, CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1 ) === false) {
   ```

   Including NET/SSH2.php is unnecessary since NET/SFTP.php includes it. Also, including Math/BigInteger.php is unnecessary since both NET/SSH2.php and Math/BigInteger.php include it.

   Calling `$rsa->setPassword('');` is also unnecessary since (I'm 80% confident) empty passwords are assumed by default and `$rsa->loadKey($privatekey, CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS1 )` can